# Refreshing UITableViewData

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have **UITableView** with a **navigationBar** at the top. I have a refresh button in the right of the navigationBar.

When clicking on the refresh button, i need to start an activity indicator, refresh the table and stop the activity indicator.

```
-(void)refreshClicked{
    [spinner startAnimating];   //UIActivityIndicatorView object
    [appDelegate readJSONData]; //this is the method which populates the array
                                //for displaying in the tableview
}
```

I want know how to refresh the table after populating the array and then how to stop the activity indicator.

thanks :)

Comment: what does `-readJSONData` do? How are you notified that the reading is completed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refresh table:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Stop activity indicator:

```
[spinner stopAnimating];
```

-----EDIT-----

From your comments, I can gather that you want to smoothly fade the spinner away and reload the tableview.

For the tableview:

You can reload sections of the tableview with a nice fade animation using the following code:

```
[tableView reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Your indexset contains all the sections you want to reload and you DO have other options for the reload animation. Look here: [UITableViewRowAnimations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITableViewRowAnimation)

To create an NSIndexSet see [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002197-BAJEBJJA)

As for your spinner, you could fade it to alpha zero before calling stopAnimating by doing this:

```
-(void)fadeSpinner
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(stopAnimation)];

    spinner.alpha = 0;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)stopAnimation
{
    [spinner stopAnimating];
}
```

Comment: Yes..This is what i did. But things happen so fast, that i don notice the activityIndicator at all.

Comment: Well it being fast would be a good thing. I'm guessing you're testing on the simulator over a Wi-Fi network. Once you do it on the device over 3G, things will slow down I'm sure :P. Either way, you could fade out the spinner before stopping it. You could also reload the tableview using a fadeanimation. See my edit for suggestions...

Comment: Thanks. Maybe it will slowdown. But i want the user to be notice that something has changed, so that they do not keep pressing the refresh button over and over. 

Where is your edit ?

Comment: Check out the edit :) Also as a best practice I tend to disable buttons when a request is being fired off and the system awaits a response. This way the user does not fire off multiple requests if they keep hitting the buttons out of frustration (which most users tend to do). I enable the button when a response comes back.

Comment: thanks for the answer. All i wanted was the user to be notified, that something has changed and the reloadSections did the trick :) 

I don need the UIactivityIndicator anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

reload data:

```
[yourTableviewController.tableView reloadData];
```

and if you need to relayout:

```
[yourTableviewController.tableView setNeedsDisplay]; 
[yourTableviewController.tableView setNeedsLayout];
```